# Change a text file to a list

Tags: python

I'm attempting to code in Python.  I have searched for answers that would satisfy my problem, but the answers all seem to be more involved than what I need.  I am attempting to open a text file and make a list of each unique word that appears.  I will eventually be adding a counter for the number of times each word appears, but I am not there yet, and am asking only for help with the list of used words.  When I attempt to call the function, i get an error of 'builtins.NameError: name 'filename' is not defined.  Because of this, I can't even see if the code works.  I would appreciate any help very much.

```
    def computeWordFrequencies(filename):
        f = open ('filename.txt','r') # Opens the file as read
        line = f.readlines() # Reads the file
        L[0] = [] # Lists the unique words that occur in the file
        L[1] = [] # Upon completion, this variable will count 
        #the number of appearances of each word
        for line in f:
        L[0].append(line.split())
        L[0] = uniqueExtend(L[0])
    return(L[0])
```

Comment: You have store the lines on your files into the variable line. Therefore you should use "for line in lines:" instead of "for line in f:"

Answer (score 1):

If you only want unique words, the following will work, actually:

```
set( open('filename.txt').read().split() )
```

This creates a list (`open('filename.txt').read().split()`) of all the words in the file. It then creates a set from this (`set( ... )`). Sets are like lists, but only hold one of each item, so doing this automatically makes all entries unique.

Note that this doesn't account for punctuation, capitalization, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.  I have already created another function to change everything to lowercase.  What do I do about the filename error, or is that just because I am calling the function incorrectly in the shell?

Comment: That's because you specified an exact filename in open, instead of the variable `filename`.

Comment: These are what I have attempted and neither work:
        computeWordFrequencies(filename)
        computeWordFrequencies(f)

Comment: You need to look at your code. The problem is not with the function call, it's with the way you use the function: I expect you've cut-and-pasted code from somewhere else, perhaps experiments you did in the interactive interpreter, and you haven't changed it to fit your function. In `open`, you have an actual filename, not the `filename` variable. Note too that you haven't indented the for loop correctly.

Comment: I appreciate the time you have spent looking at this comparatively elementary code, and for the suggestions.  I've checked the indentations in the IDE, and think I probably typed it wrong on here.  I am still a bit confused what you mean about using a filename variable, because everything I have read (admittedly probably not as much as you) suggests that  one is meant to put the name of the file - not a variable -, when opening the file initially.  That being said, I will go dig through books and websites again to see if I can understand what you mean.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted to write something like this:

```
def computeWordFrequencies(filename):
    f = open (filename,'r') # Opens the file as read
    line = f.readlines() # Reads the file
    L[0] = [] # Lists the unique words that occur in the file
    L[1] = [] # Upon completion, this variable will count 
    #the number of appearances of each word
    for line in lines:
        L[0].append(line)
        L[0] = uniqueExtend(L[0])
    return(L[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

def computeWordFrequencies(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        words = [word for line in f for word in line.split()]
    words_count = Counter(words)
    unique_words = words_count.keys()
    return unique_words

computeWordFrequencies('filename.txt')
```

The problem with the name error is because I assume you call the function with the variable filename which you didnt define.

Counter is your friend to count the frequency. It takes a list and returns a dict of words as keys and counts as values thus Counter(['a','a','b']) would return {'a':2,'b':1}

the with open syntax is called context manager and you should better use this because it takes cares of closing the file as well which you didnt do in your code.

I am not really sure how you want to use the frequency counts but essentially you have a working example now so you can decide for yourself.

Make sure when you run this python code filename is in the same directory as your code.

Let me know in case you need more help with this.